# Do we need both a "fighter" and a "fighter-jet" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have two quite similar tags:

- [fighter](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fighter) with 10 questions
- [fighter-jet](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fighter-jet) with 126 questions

Do we really need both? Should we edit [fighter](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fighter) away?

Comment: We don't but I think you suggested getting rid of the wrong tag!

Comment: Suggested title: "Fight [fighter-jet]"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick skim of the fighter-jet questions suggests that most of them fall into a few classes:

- questions about fighters in general and it doesn't much matter what kind of engine;
- questions about modern fighters in general, which are jet-powered because they're modern but that's incidental;
- questions about a specific fighter.

To me, the only real benefit of a fighter-jet tag would be for

- questions about aspects of jet fighters in general, that don't apply to other methods of propulsion

and I don't see many questions about that, so it doesn't seem to be a very useful tag.

Is this a case where synonymizing would work? Or should we just turn all the fighter-jets into fighters?  (If the latter, I would, as usual, encourage people to only do a few at a time, to avoid swamping the front page.)

Answer (score 6):

### *vroom*

[image]
<sup>no jet</sup>

Comment: bloody hell, I'm an idiot. I understood only now, AFTER I edited, what you meant. darn it. Should we edit fighter-jet away and have only fighter? we have a jet tag anyway.

Comment: @Federico I would say yes!  If there is a question specific to a "fighter jet" it could always be tagged "[fighter] [jet]".

Comment: @Lnafziger Or, rather, about jet fighters but not about any specific one. If it was about a specific fighter, it seems unlikely that the [jet] tag would be useful. (Otherwise, we'd need to go tag every single post about, say, the 747 with [jet]. But why stop there? It's a monoplane, it has tricycle landing gear, it was built in the USA, it carries passengers, etc. We don't tag all of that stuff unless it's relevant to the question.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Hence why I said a specific question about a "fighter jet".  If it's a more generic question that isn't related to it being a jet, then obviously the jet tag wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Change the aircraft role, if the aircraft was an attack aircraft, where both jet and turbo-prop and other non jet powerplants are still viable. Would it be functional to have just attack-jet